# Getting the wrong answer when getting the sum of column name

Tags: mysql

I have a problem in getting the sum of one of my column names in database (PRICE). If I insert 1000.00 and 3600.00 to get the sum of them, I am getting 4.00 instead of 4600.00. But when the total is below 1000 I get the correct answer.

[image: Sample pic here]

Comment: Not possible, unless your data and/or query has a problem.  Can you include sample data and the query you are using?

Comment: Provide a [example].

Comment: I edit the question and added the sample picture. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your `price_per_case` column is `char` or `varchar` column rather than a numeric column such as `decimal(10,2)`. So, it is converting the column to `double` but ignoring everything after the `,` character (and probably issuing warnings during the conversion). You can verify this by trying the following:

```
select '1,234' + '3,456';
```

You will end up with `4`;

You should try running:

```
update ordered set price_per_case = replace(price_per_case, ',', ''); /* get rid of commas */
```

Then you should change the type of this column to `decimal(10,2)` or some appropriate precision.

Comment: Yes sir right im using varchar, i tried the code you gave sir and it worked but when the sum is whole number and im not getting the .00 in the end. Example: sum expected 4000.00, what i got: 4000. I think the better way to do is change the datatype. Thank sir

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the machine when you are programming have different “Locale” of MySql Server (are both in the same machine)?
In this case also format currency/double/decimal is different. 
To avoid that you need to change Locale in you .NET method/sub/function before/into you get query result

```
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("it-IT")
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("it-IT")
```

or change Locale in MySql

```
SET lc_time_names = 'it_IT'; Here continue your query
```

In this example I have used Italian Locale

Comment: The problem is im using datatype varchar instead of decimal, credits to ronald aaronson.

Comment: Even if you are using a VARCHAR type, if the "Locale" on machine where you are programming on vb.net (I assume you pass this data from vb.net) have the same “Locale” as MySql SERVER, the decimal separator had to be the same.
However, I'm glad you solved it.